# Hide Kendo Grid toolbar using Grid ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having Kendo Razor Grid in which I am having a Toolbar with Create button. I am having 2 different kendo grids in same page. I want to Hide only one of the Grid's Toolbar. How can I do this ?

We can hide Toolbar using the below code. As it points to class, toolbar on both grids will hide. I want only one of them to hide. How can I do this ?

```
$(".k-grid-toolbar").hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add unique id attribute for each toolbar.

such as  the first Grid's Toolbar's id as `myid1`, the second Grid's Toolbar's id as **myid2** . Let's hiding the frist Grid's Toolbar, something like this,

```
$(".k-grid-toolbar#myid1").hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you just add the `id` of the grid you want to target in your jQuery selector?

`$("#GridID .k-grid-toolbar").hide();`